# Is it possible to check NTPd status on a Busybox system?

Tags: monitoring, ntpd, busybox

I need to know if current date/time is reliable in a small embedded Linux system Busybox-based.

I have Busybox ntpd running, but apparently there is no program to to query status.

On a more conventional Linux installation I would use ntpdc, ntpq, ntpstat or even timedatectl, but none of these is available on this Busybox/Buildroot system.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BusyBox does not provide the IPC/RPC interfaces that are needed to query the status of a running BusyBox NTP daemon, so even if you install one of the mentioned query utilities they will not be able to talk to BusyBox `ntpd`.

Running `ntpd -w` as mentioned in another answer will simply start another BusyBox `ntpd` instance from scratch and this new one will not talk to an already running `ntpd` process.

There is however another way to get status information from BusyBox `ntpd`, by using its program/script interface. See the -S flag:

```
~# ntpd --help
BusyBox v1.30.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: ntpd [-dnqNwl] [-I IFACE] [-S PROG] [-p PEER]...

NTP client/server

        -d      Verbose (may be repeated)
        -n      Do not daemonize
        -q      Quit after clock is set
        -N      Run at high priority
        -w      Do not set time (only query peers), implies -n
        -S PROG Run PROG after stepping time, stratum change, and every 11 min
        -p PEER Obtain time from PEER (may be repeated)
        -l      Also run as server on port 123
        -I IFACE Bind server to IFACE, implies -l
```

The specified program will be executed regularly depending on different time events and NTP information is supplied as args to the program and in its environment. I find no info about this interface so the source code seems to be the docs in this case:

https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/ntpd.c

Look up the function `run_script()` and you can see that it calls the external program with `action` as argument and `stratum`, `freq_drift_ppm`, `poll_interval` and `offset` as environment variables.

Chances are that your embedded Linux distro is already hooking into this interface. On my OpenWrt box `ntpd` is running with this command line:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpd -n -N -S /usr/sbin/ntpd-hotplug -p 0.openwrt.pool.ntp.org -p 1.openwrt.pool.ntp.org -p 2.openwrt.pool.ntp.org -p 3.openwrt.pool.ntp.org
```

and as you can see the program interface is hooking into OpenWrt's procd hotplug support. In OpenWrt this means that you instead add your NTP scripts to `/etc/hotplug.d/ntp` but the information supplied to your script is still the same, see NTP section here:

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/hotplug

Answer (score 0):

`ntpd -w` will provide some information, such as what the current offset is from your NTP servers.